# Why is $\frac{\sum_{i=1}x_iy_i}{\sum_{i=1}x_i^2}\ne \frac{\sum_{i=1}y_i}{\sum_{i=1}x_i}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I know they are not equal, but I am unable to come up with a convincing explanation as to why they are not equal. Cancelling the $x_i$'s when they are part of the summand is prohibited; Can anyone provide a decent argument as to why this is the case?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking for a counterexample?

Comment: @Gaffney Sure, that would be great thanks or an explanation would be nice

Comment: To cancel, you have to have a common factor. You don't: instead you can do something like $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i}{x_1} y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i^2}{x_1}}$ (replacing the $1$ with whatever you want). In fact it can happen that the left side is defined and the right side is not, for instance with $n=2,x_1=1,x_2=-1,y_1=1,y_2=1$.

Comment: @Ian Thanks, and $x_i$ is not a common factor because....?

Comment: You need the *same* common factor; $x_i$ is not one number (in general).

Comment: Is this a joke? Does it seem that $\dfrac {ab + cd} {a^2 + c^2} = \dfrac {b + d} {a + c}$?

Comment: @Alex Why did you say that? Sure I was laughing all the time I wrote it. What's simple to you may not be so simple to me.

Comment: @AlexM. I work with high school students and it seems to be a very common misconception.

Comment: @BLAZE: Not to offend you, but you've got some reputation already, you've acquired some medals and you've correctly answered some undergraduate-level questions, and it baffles me how somebody with university-level knowledge on some topics of mathematics does not know something elementary, from pre-high-school.

Comment: @AlexM Well that does deserve an explanation I guess; I use this site primarily to learn. All I wanted was a concrete example/explanation as to why they are not equal I already stated in the question; that I _know_ they are not equal. This post was designed to promote a decent explanation. Maybe summation theory is simply not my strong-point.

Comment: @BLAZE: Ah, ok then, I apologize, I had misunderstood your question.

Comment: @AlexM It's fine; no need for apologies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the $y_i$'s be all $1$, and let's write the summation explicitly, like so:
$${x_1 + x_2 + \cdots +x_n \over x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \dots +x_n^2} \neq {1 + 1 + \dots +1 \over x_1 + x_2 + \dots +x_n} = \frac{n}{x_1 + x_2 + \dots +x_n}$$
Does it seem convincing here that the $x_i$'s can't cancel? It's just not a valid logical step.

For a specific counterexample, take $x_i = 1,2,3,4$. Then we have
$${1+2+3+4 \over 1 + 4 + 9 + 16} = \frac{10}{30} = \frac13 \neq \frac25 = \frac4{10} = \frac4{1 + 2 + 3 + 4}$$
Therefore we cannot cancel the $x_i$'s.

Comment: In other words, asking for a convincing explanation why it's not true is like asking for a convincing explanation why $\frac ab+\frac cd=\frac{a+b}{c+d}$ is not true. It just ain't.

Comment: @GregMartin Exactly.

Comment: @silvascientist Thanks for the explanation and counter-example.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the simpler case when $n = 2$ (the upper bound for the summation index). Assume that $\dfrac {ab + cd} {a^2 + c^2} = \dfrac {b + d} {a + c}$. After cross-multiplication and canceling of similar terms, you may grup the remaining ones as $(a-c) (ad - bc) = 0$. This shows that, in order for that equality to be true, either $a = c$ (i.e. $x_1 = \dots = x_n$, which means that you may simplify a common factor), or your numbers have to verify a very special relationship ($ad - bc = 0$), so the equality cannot hold in general, for arbitrary values.

Comment: I think the answer could be improved by adding a concrete example.

Comment: @Farnight: I could do it, but I am *certain* that finding some $a,b,c,d$ that make the above equality false is a very good exercise for the OP, and I am also *certain* that he has the abilities to solve it for himself.

Comment: @AlexM No offence taken, thanks for your answer (+1)

Comment: @BLAZE: Maybe the expanded version of my answer better addresses   your question.

Comment: @AlexM Yes that's looking pretty good thank you

Comment: Speaking of being certain: "... he or she has the abilities to solve it for himself or herself."

Comment: @GregMartin: I refuse to bow to political correctness, I hate that politically-motivated pervertion of "sexist, non-inclusive" English and, fortunately, I live in a country that still doesn't force me to do the above.

Comment: Your use of the phrase "political correctness", as usual, is a deflection without substance (as is the bizarre non-sequiter about national laws). I am simply pointing out, to thoughtful readers, that assumptions about mathematicians automatically being male are still present—and, judging by your hostile reaction, defended by some. I further assert that such assumptions and biases are harmful (as evidenced by the current gender inequity in mathematics).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer of mine is not rigorous enough but I will give it a try because it gives some kind of alternative view on questions of this sort so I will add it maybe just to have a variety of views on the same question.

Suppose that we view $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iy_i$ as a function of $2n$ variables $x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...,y_n$. Then, in the same spirit, the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$ could be viewed as the function of $n$ variables $x_1,...x_n$. The sum $\sum_{i=1}^{n} {x_i}^2$  as a function of also the $n$ variables $x_1,...,x_n$ and sum $\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i$ as a function of $n$ variables $y_1,...y_n$.

Let us write now $a(x_1,...x_n,y_1,...y_n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iy_i$ and $b(x_1,...x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$ and $c(x_1,...x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} {x_i}^2$ and $d(y_1,...y_n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i$.

Now, if we suppose that your equality is true then we would have

$a(x_1,...x_n,y_1,...y_n)=d(y_1,...y_n) \dfrac {c(x_1,...x_n)}{b(x_1,...x_n)}$

So we would have that the function of $2n$ variables is equal to the product of two functions, one that depends on the first $n$ variables and the second that depends on the remaining $n$ variables, and, intuitively, this will, I guess, happen rarely, and in this case it is only always true when $n=1$.